# Testing DataTime in Rails with rspec

Tags: datetime, rspec, tdd

I'm testing the model (control.rb) with rspec in rails and I'm having a problem with datetimes. It doesn't succed because a difference of 00001000000000 between what I expect and what I got. This is my code

```
describe ".graphic_data_for_all_days" do
  before do
    Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now)
  end

  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

it "the controls are ordered from older to newer" do
    # time = DateTime.now.to_i
    # DateTime.stub!(:now).and_return{DateTime.at(time += 5) }
    control = FactoryGirl.create(
      :control, 
      user: user, 
      level: 120,
      day: Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now)
      )
    control2 = Control.create(
      user_id: user.id, 
      level: 106, 
      period: "pre-breakfast", 
      day: Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now + 3.hours)
      )
    control3 = Control.create(
      user_id: user.id, 
      level: 104, 
      period: "pre-breakfast", 
      day: Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now + 6.hours)
      )
    control4 = Control.create(
      user_id: user.id, 
      level: 104, 
      period: "pre-breakfast", 
      day: Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now + 9.hours)
      )
     graphic_data_for_all_days = Control.graphic_data_for_all_days(user.id)
     expect(graphic_data_for_all_days).to eq ([{
      name: "day", 
      data:[
        [Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now).strftime("%I:%M%p").to_time.utc.to_i * 1000, 120],
        [(Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now + 3.hours)).strftime("%I:%M%p").to_time.utc.to_i * 1000, 106],
        [(Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now + 6.hours)).strftime("%I:%M%p").to_time.utc.to_i * 1000, 104],
        [(Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now + 9.hours)).strftime("%I:%M%p").to_time.utc.to_i * 1000, 104] 
        ]
        }])
  end
```

This is config/environments/test.rb

```
        config.after_initialize do
  # Set Time.now to September 1, 2008 10:05:00 AM (at this instant), but allow it to move forward
      t = DateTime.now
      Timecop.travel(t)
      end
```

And this is what the console gives me back

```
    expected: [{:name=>"day", :data=>[[1418881560000, 120], [1418892360000, 106], [1418913960000, 104], [1418946360000, 104]]}]
            got: [{:name=>"day", :data=>[[1418899560000, 120], [1418910360000, 106], [1418931960000, 104]]}, {:name=>"day", :data=>[[1418877960000, 104]]}]
```

I don't know what can I do to pass the test. I would thanks if someone can help me.

Comment: use Timecop not DateTime.now

Comment: I've installed Timecop but it still doesn't work. I've edited my question updating the Timecop features according the documentation for you to check if I've done something wrong or I'm missing something. Thank you anyway¡¡